# DateTime Format in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5

I experiencing a strange behavior of C#. Its some thing like this..

```
var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

I expecting out to be

```
04/24/2009
```

but in actuall its returning

```
04-24-2009
```

and my OS culture is en-GB, I'm using .Net 3.5 and WPF

any solutions please... ???

Comment: Have you stepped through the code and completed a "QuickWatch" on that DateTime.Now.ToString()?

Comment: If you're using "en-GB" you should be using a date format of "dd/MM/yyyy". For US date formats of "MM/dd/yyyy" you should be using "en-US".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the MSDN docs for custom date and time format strings, `/` is a placeholder:

> Represents the date separator defined
>   in the current
>   DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator
>   property. This separator is used to
>   differentiate years, months, and days.

If you want a definite slash, use "MM'/'dd'/'yyyy":

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy")
```

Answer (score 3):

It uses the separator set up in the regional settings, since "/" is the substitute character for the separator.

You can create your own DateTimeFormat instance with different separators.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling ToString on the date itself and passing the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture object:

```
string date = yourDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```