# convert string to date(dd/MM/yyyyy) format in c#

Tags: c#, date-format

i have a query string with format MM/DD/YYYY

I am using it in c# like

```
DateTime d = Request.QueryString["dateTime"].toString();
```

its giving me a lot of error saying the date time format is not recognized. If i manually change the datetime in browser address bar (query string) to dd/mm/yyyy then the program just works fine.

I cannot change the query string, is there a way in c# to get it from browser and then convert into date like dd/mm/yyyy please?

edit:
the query string:

```
http://localhost:49543/HM/Admin/ViewDetails.aspx?OrderNo=10&DateCreated=08/30/2010
```

so you can see the datecreated part is in MM/DD/YYYY format.
I am not able to grab it from c#. If I manually change that to 30/08/2010, it works

Comment: Give an example query string that you need to match.

Comment: Request.QueryString["dateTime"] already is a string. No need to use ToString() method.

Comment: A DateTime variable doesn't have a format, it just contains a date. Only when you convert it to/from a string, you need a format.

Answer (score 7):

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.QueryString["dateTime"], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I don't think he means that that is how the string is formatted, but rather that is what he wants to create. He needs to post the example QS.

Comment: Hi, this is the real QS: http://localhost:49543/HM/Admin/ViewDetails.aspx?OrderNo=10&DateCreated=08/30/2010

Comment: changed http with gaps because it was becoming a link: http : // localhost:49543/HM/Admin/ViewDetails.aspx?OrderNo=10&DateCreated=08/30/2010

Comment: @locusthorde, I fixed it. The 'yyyy' had to be lowercase, not uppercase as I had first written it

Comment: the QS is in the "MM/dd/yyyy" format (says OP), not "dd/MM/yyyy".

Comment: Hi Thomas, now there is a new error: String reference not set to an instance of a String.
Parameter name: s

s is not even in the string! I am completely lost !

Comment: @Hans Kesting, yes Sir, I know that, I want to convert it into DateTime Variable, with dd/MM/yyyy format. thats the trouble!

Comment: @locusthorde, "s" is the name of the first parameter to the ParseExact method. You must be passing it a null string. You need to check that the "dateTime" query parameter is present before you try to convert it

Answer (score 5):

**How to turn string from request into `DateTime`:**

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.QueryString["dateTime"], "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

Comment: the first one, I tried it, it says that the iFormatProvider to String cannot be done manually. its throwing 2 errors on that line!

(and I want the first case scenario - sorry if my question was confusing!)

Comment: @locusthorde: OK, sorry for posting without trying it. I changed the answer to something that works for me. (It will still throw an exception if the input string is not *precisely* in this dd/MM/yyyy format. You might want to catch this exception and handle it appropriately.)

Answer (score 2):

DateTime.ParseExact is the solution you seek for.
But I recommend you to validate the querystring data with a function as follows:

```
bool isValidDate(string dtStr) {
    string pattern = @"^(([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])\/([0]\d|[1][0-2])\/[2][0]\d{2})$)";
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex re = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern);
    return re.IsMatch(dtStr);
}
```

EDIT 1: Besides ParseExact, you can use  the following:

```
DateTime.Parse(dateString, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("tr-TR"))
```

Turkish datetime format is dd/MM/YYYY.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Parsing:
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(Request.QueryString["dateTime"].toString());

// Conversion:
string dString = d.ToWhateverFormatYouWant();
```

And here's some info on formatting dates:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(VS.71).aspx

Comment: i want it in dateTime variable type itself!

Answer (score 1):

[DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) could be a great option..

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work

```
    DateTime d = 
           DateTime.ParseExact(Request.QueryString["dateTime"], 
           "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy",    
           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I faced something similar: [DateTime Format in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785795/datetime-format-in-c)